# How to handle URL parameter for mobile site

Tags: seo, google-search-console, robots.txt

I have a phpBB forum with a skin for mobile users. Some javascript detects your device/resolution and sends you to the mobile skin or not. The URLs remain the same, it is based on a cookie.

People that are on a larger screen, can still choose to use the mobile skin, by pressing a button that will send them to `example.com/current_page?mobile=mobile`.

I have 2 problems with this:

1. Duplicate pages on Google. I do not see any doubles popping up yet, but it is bound to happen right?
2. Sometimes Google indexes the mobile link. This causes desktop users to go to the mobile skin automatically and is certainly not intended functionality.

Will `disallow *?mobile=mobile` in `robots.txt` solve my problem?

Can disallowing the parameter in GWT help? The parameter does not change the content, only the layout, so I can put it on ignore, but will (could) it help with my problem?

Comment: Can't you use a cookie instead of the mobile query string?

Comment: I didn't write it myself, and I would rather fix it through GWT or robots.txt or the like than trying to figure out how it works exactly. I barely know php too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Canonical links to the rescue*

There's no need to use robots to block urls that are used by your users instead what you should be using is *[canonical links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)* on the desktop version, by doing so you are informing Google that the content originates from this page this will resolve any duplicate problems.

*Responsive design is the way forward*

Nowadays it's agreed by Google, web design and seo professionals that responsive is ideal for most websites. [*Responsive design will allow you to serve your website to multiple devices*](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details#why_responsive_design) the way you want it too without having to create multiple urls. Because your only be using one url any backlinks and social mentions gained you are boosting mobiles, tablets and desktops, of course canonical links will help but ideally you should use responsive and canonical links too.

*Picking a template based on a framework*

If your using free templates then I recommend you look for frameworks based on or have your designer to make his own framework or use one of the common open source ones.

> **[SOURCE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/47003/20604)**
>
> - [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
> - [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)
> - [Base](http://matthewhartman.github.com/base/)
> - [Gumby](http://gumbyframework.com/)
> - [Kube](http://imperavi.com/kube/)
> - [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/)
> - [Less Framework 4](http://lessframework.com/)
> - [Golden Grid System](http://goldengridsystem.com/)
> - [Fluid Baseline Grid](http://fluidbaselinegrid.com/)
> - [Columnal](http://www.columnal.com/)
> - [The Semantic Grid System](http://semantic.gs/)
> - [1140 Grid System](http://cssgrid.net/)
> - [320 and Up Grid](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/)
> - [The Goldilocks Approach](http://goldilocksapproach.com/)
> - [BluCSS](http://designlunatic.com/projects/blucss/)
> - [Frameless](http://framelessgrid.com/)
> - [Gridless](http://thatcoolguy.github.com/gridless-boilerplate/)
> - [Amazium](http://www.amazium.co.uk/)
> - [Less Framework](http://lessframework.com/)

Comment: "canonical links on the desktop version" - just to clarify, is that _canonical links **to** the desktop version_? Or _canonical links **from** the desktop version to the mobile site_?

Comment: Canonical links on the desktop version only.

Answer (score 1):

Create a subdomain example `www.mobi.example.com` and place the robots & duplicate web page files in the `.mobi` folder. Disallow robots to not index that sub domain folder.

Redirect them from `www.example.com` to `www.mobi.example.com` with JavaScript (you then know that they have a tablet or android device. you should look at using bootstrap for responsiveness however)

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 <!--



if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://www.mobi.example.com";

  }
  //-->
</script>
```

Cookies are not always a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able edit the code on the ?mobile=mobile indepently from the main page? If so rather than using just the canonical tags, maybe you should also be using the markup for mobile pages.

On the desktop page, add a special link rel="alternate" tag pointing to the corresponding mobile URL. This helps Googlebot discover the location of your site's mobile pages.

```
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)"
      href="http://www.example.com/current_page?mobile=mobile" >
```

On the mobile page, add a link rel="canonical" tag pointing to the corresponding desktop URL.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/current_page/" >
```

You can also defined the tags in a sitemap.xml file.  More info here [Building Smartphone-Optimized Websites](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details)